# How to make .map() valid in old browser by using $.map()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I have this code:

```
var Names = $(this).closest("a").map(function() {
     return $(this).text().replace(/\s/g,"."); }).get();
```

But this ^ doesn't work on IE8, and I need to write code above using JQuery. Here is my new code:

```
var Names = $.map($(this).closest("a"), function() {
     return $(this).text().replace(/\s/g,"."); }).get();
```

But it doesn't work, How can I fix it?

Comment: `.get()` at second version is not needed , `$.map()` returns an array. Can you describe "it doesn't work" ?

Comment: @guest271314 I removed `.get()` and there isn't any error now, But still doesn't work .. and it means `Names` array is empty while it shouldn't be ..

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippets or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: @guest271314 Well please take a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/v0c390tx/) and [this](https://jsfiddle.net/v0c390tx/1/)

Comment: second one can't use `this` , use callback arguments. No reason the first shouldn't work though...what errors are thrown? Also show what the context of your code is. We don't know where it is being used

Comment: @charlietfl There isn't any error, just their outputs aren't identical, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/v0c390tx/) and [this](https://jsfiddle.net/v0c390tx/1/)

Comment: Not using second version properly  see https://jsfiddle.net/v0c390tx/2/ Where's the rest of the real code?

Comment: Show more code (HTML). It may be that $(this).closest("a") is returning an empty wrapped set in the first place.

Comment: @charlietfl Oh .. great .. thank you

Comment: You already **are** using [`$.fn.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), and it should work like that. What's the error you are getting?

Comment: @Bergi I'm trying to use `JQuery.map()` instead of `.map()`. Because `.map()` isn't defined in IE8 and I need to use jquery library for mapping. Now all I need is https://jsfiddle.net/v0c390tx/6/

Comment: @stack: No, you are using `$.fn.map` which *is* defined! There's nothing wrong with it! What is not defined in IE8 is `Array.prototype.map`. The `closest` method returns a jQuery collection, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

The second version should be like this: *(as @charlietfl said in comments)*

```
var Names = $.map($(this).closest("a"), function(el) {
     return $(el).text().replace(/\s/g,"."); });
```

Comment: whole thing doesn't make sense. `$(this).closest("a")` can only be one element so no need to use map at all

Comment: @charlietfl In [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v0c390tx/2/) there is three element and I need to get all of them .. Thant's not just one element, ok you tell me, how can I do that without `map()` ?

Comment: @charlietfl And my last question, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/v0c390tx/3/) works for me, may you please tell me how can I convert it to `$.map()` ?

Comment: You have never provided enough code for anyone to really understand what you are doing in the real code

Comment: @charlietfl Ok, All I need is just same results in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/v0c390tx/6/), pay attention to the comment that I wore under the code